# GitHub Jekyll Post Not allowing Hyperlinks

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to work on a simple webpage based on Jekyll Templates available on GitHub pages.

I was able to get a template up and running and am trying to modify a post structure.  I would like to add hyperlinks in the post, and having a hard time.  Here is the post definition...

---

### layout: default
modal-id: 1
date: 2023-03-18
img: AndroidAppStore.png
alt: image-alt
project-date: March 2023
client: customerX
category: typeY
description: some description...

### Header

this is more text here.

link

I would like to have a hyperlink in the description field above, but I have tried both Markdown and HTLM syntax in the description field above and none are working.

Further, all the text (## Header and below) doesn't show up.  If I change the Layout to Post (layout: post), I get the "## Header and below" but my whole template page breaks and that is the only thing I see.

I want the simple link available.